# Show that two generator systems have the same sigma algebra - concrete example / problem

Tags: measure-theory

Let  $G = \{(-a,a):a>0\}$ and $H = \{[-a,a]:a>0\}$  be two generator systems on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $\sigma(G)=\sigma(H)$.

Basically I want to show that $G \subseteq \sigma(H)$ and $H \subseteq \sigma(G)$ then $\sigma(H) = \sigma(G)$. I have tried to show the first inclusion:

$G \subseteq \sigma(H)$:

Every open interval of the type $(-a,a), a>0$ can be written as a difference to closed intervals, i.e. $\forall a>0:$ $(-a,a) = [-a,a] \cap (\{-a\} \cup \{a\} )^c = [-a,a]\cap [(-\infty,-a) \cup (-a,a) \cup (a,\infty)]  $. Now I know that $[-a,a] \in \sigma(H)$, $(-\infty,-a) \in \sigma(H)$, $(a,\infty) \in \sigma(H)$ but I run in to a "circular" argument as I have not shown yet that $(-a,a) \in \sigma(H)$? I am not sure how I can proceed here.

I have also tried to use the fact that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} [-a+1/n, a-1/n]=(-a,a), a>0$ to argue that the left hand side is in $\sigma(H)$. However, for this to be true I need that $[-a+1/n,a-1/n] \in H$ which I am not sure whether is fruitful.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: For large enough $n$, the interval in question is in $H$ because it is the same as $[-(a-\frac 1n), a - \frac 1n]$ which is of the form $[-b,b]$ where $b = a-\frac 1n>0$.

Comment: For $G \subseteq \sigma(H)$, I would say (as you guessed): every set $(-a,a)$ is a countable union of sets $[-b,b]$.

Comment: Alright. So is this all that is needed for $G \subseteq \sigma(H)$? The other way around, i.e. $H \subseteq \sigma(G)$ would it suffice to just use the fact that $[-a,a] = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (-a-1/n,a+1/n)$? Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer

Comment: @Sinadal11 The relation you've written for $[-a,a] = \ldots$ looks wrong. You probably mean $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} (-a-\frac 1n , a+\frac 1n)$ instead of $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}$, in which case it is correct and you're good!

Comment: Alright, yep of course! Now, after I conclude that $\sigma(G)=\sigma(H)$, I am to show that $[0,1] \notin \sigma(G)$ and thereby conclude that $\sigma(G)$ does not generate the borel sigma algebra. Can you clue me in as to how to do this? @SarveshRavichandranIyer